# Fusionner deux compléments du nom

Tags: coordination, compléments

Une liste non numérotée (présentation) comportera l'article :

- Étudiants d'un large éventail d'âges. Étudiants avec des problèmes en dys.

Puis-je le reformuler comme ci-dessous ?

- Étudiants d'un large éventail d'âges et avec des problèmes en dys.

Ou le sens n'est plus le même ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oui, si les étudiants en question ont tous des problèmes « en dys ».

Je préférerais écrire (en ajoutant une note de bas de page si le terme dys n'a pas déjà été expliqué) :

> Étudiants d'âges variés souffrant de problèmes en dys<sup>1</sup>.

<sup>1</sup><sub>dyslexie/dysphasie/dyspraxie</sub>.

Comment: Merci pour la réponse. Si les étudiants en question n'ont pas tous des problèmes en dys ne puis-je pas faire le fusionnement ?

Comment: Étudiants d'âges variés dont certains souffrent de problèmes en dys.

Answer (score 3):

Pour moi le sens n'est plus le même.

- La première formulation me fais penser à une liste dont il faut agréger les entrées pour en appréhender l'ensemble. Cela concerne donc les étudiants d'âge variés, les étudiants dys et les étudiants dys d'âge variés
- La seconde formulation correspond à une liste de critères qui doivent tous être respectés simultanément. Cela concerne donc les étudiants dys d'âge variés mais ne concerne ni les étudiants dys qui n'ont pas d'âge variés (ce qui n'a d'ailleurs aucun sens), ni les étudiants d'âge variés non dys.

Pour moi, la reformulation correcte est : Étudiants d'un large éventail d'âges **ou** avec des problèmes en dys.

Si l'on pousse la reformulation à L’extrême, l'ensemble des étudiants d'âge variés inclus tous les étudiants peu importe leur âge. Si on ajoute à ce groupe l'ensemble des étudiants dys on obtient toujours l'ensemble des étudiants. Une reformulation plus poussée serait donc tout simplement : `Tous les étudiants`